# Getting image from web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'll explain what I want to do: let's take this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glbMA.jpg) as example. I want to download this picture and open it in my application, using Picture Box. I think I'll need to use
`Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(xxxx);`
and what should I put at "xxxx" place? Script I saw was written in Delphi an looked like this:

```
Value := copys (searchPage, '<link rel="image_src" href="', '">');
GetPicture (Value);
```

Any advice?

Comment: What did you find when you researched this? It will be easier to help if we know what problems you faced while trying to do this on your own.

Comment: @Patrick - I didn't know how to download image and then load it in Picture Box, since I'm a newbie and it's first thing I'm doing on my own.
jac - didn't know how to name my problem, so I couldn't find thing you linked. Thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Image i = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/glbMA.jpg");
src.EndInit();
i.Source = src;
```